# Grab the content of a div,which is inside another div

Tags: php

I am doing an application where I want to grab the content of div,which is inside a div.In my application I want to grab the content of `<li></li>,`which is inside `<ul class="snippet-list"></ul>`.The ul class is inside `<div data-analyticsid="related"></div>`.Is there any regular expression like preg_match to grab the data.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: [Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML. Use an HTML parser!](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/476)

Comment: @RavinderSingh I tried  preg_match("'<ul class=\"snippet-list\">(.*?)</div>'", $page_all, $images);. But the problem is there is another <ul class="snippet-list"> </ul>.Thats why I specifically asked the <ul class="snippet-list"> </ul> inside <div data-analyticsid="related"> </div>.

Comment: so you want to get all the li's content inside this ul.

Comment: @RavinderSingh Yes.You are right.

Comment: check the answer i posted and accept it as answer if it worked for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

   $("ul.snippet-list li").each(function() {
       var html = jQuery(this).html();
   });

});

</script>
```